# Error: The method query(String, String, String, null, null, null, null) is undefined for the type

Tags: android, database, sqlite

Here is my Class:

```
public class CikmisSorular2011 extends Activity{ 

    String[] columns = new String[]{"soru","cevapA","cevapB","cevapC","cevapD","cevapE"}; 
    Cursor c = db.query("sorular","columns","id=1",null,null,null,null); 
    // error is above: The method query(String, String, String, null, null, null, null) is undefined for the type Veritabani

}
```

the `Veritabani` database is:

```
private static class VeritabaniHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public VeritabaniHelper(Context contextim) {
        super(contextim, DATABASE_ISIM, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    } 

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) { 
         db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLO + " (" + KEY_ROW_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , " + KEY_SORU + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_CEVAPA + " TEXT NOT NULL," + KEY_CEVAPB + " TEXT NOT NULL," + KEY_CEVAPC + " TEXT NOT NULL," + KEY_CEVAPD + " TEXT NOT NULL," + KEY_CEVAPE + " TEXT NOT NULL);");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `db` in your `CikmisSorular2011` is your `VeritabaniHelper` object, call e.g. `getWritableDatabase()` on it and then run your `query()` on the returned `SQLiteDatabase` object.